# convert list of strings to ICollection of MailAddresses

Tags: c#

`ICollection<MailAddress> toCollection = to.Split(',');`

This fails because strings aren't automatically `MailAddress`...

How can you iterate over the strings, make each instance a `MailAddress` and then add those to a new `ICollection`?

Comment: You can't.  Only add checks to verify a string is a valid mail address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
using System.Linq;
....
IEnumerable<MailAddress> addresses = to.Split(',').Select(i => new MailAddress(i));
```

**EDIT**: Making it an `ICollection<MailAddress>`

```
ICollection<MailAddress> collection = to.Split(',').Select(i => new MailAddress(i)).[ToList | ToArray]()];
```

Comment: ahh got it. And calling `ToArray()` makes it an ICollection. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobIRR You can use `ToList()` as well to make it an `ICollection<MailAddress>`.